# Why Flexapp progress is stopped?

Tags: android, ios

I use flexapp for develop mobile app. I add a view, a label and a list. I add a loop progress in view.  When i build application, application is stoped and progress is not work. My problem is loop progress is not stoped. I don't add any condition. I Close all application and delete loop progress. But its not working any database progress. Before i understand my problem. I don't add any load data progress. My problem is fixed.

Comment: English please. You have to use English here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to make sure that the condition is correct in the loop action. Otherwise, it may be locked due to infinite looping. A business plan was created to take the technical considerations necessary for not freezing.

When the Flexapp app closes, all temporary data from the webservices is deleted and the app acts as if it were loaded from scratch. However, local table records are kept and even if Flexapp is closed and reopened, there is no change. This information is stored in your app.flx project file.